# audio playing in constructor instead of play method

Tags: java, audio, javasound, java-audio

so I've been working on my game library and I just got working on the sound aspect of it. But the problems are that the Sound starts playing from the constructor instead of the play method and also the stop doesn't work for the constructor and only the play method.

I tried debugging the code but I didn't get any results from it. I also tried using the stop method before doing the play method but that didn't work either

below is the code,

```
import java.io.*;
import java.io.File;

import java.io.IOException;

import javax.sound.sampled.*;

// class stuff

    private Clip clip;
    private FloatControl fc;
    
    public SoundLoader(File file) {
        try {
            InputStream audioSource = new FileInputStream(file);
            InputStream bufferedInput = new BufferedInputStream(audioSource);
            AudioInputStream audioInputStream = AudioSystem.getAudioInputStream(bufferedInput);
            AudioFormat baseFormat = audioInputStream.getFormat();
            AudioFormat decodedFormat = new AudioFormat(AudioFormat.Encoding.PCM_SIGNED,
                    baseFormat.getSampleRate(),
                    baseFormat.getSampleSizeInBits(),
                    baseFormat.getChannels(),
                    baseFormat.getFrameSize(),
                    baseFormat.getFrameRate(),
                    false
                    );
            AudioInputStream decodedAudioInputStream = AudioSystem.getAudioInputStream(decodedFormat, audioInputStream);
            clip = AudioSystem.getClip();
            clip.open(decodedAudioInputStream);
            fc = (FloatControl)clip.getControl(FloatControl.Type.MASTER_GAIN);
        } catch (UnsupportedAudioFileException | IOException | LineUnavailableException e) {
            // TODO Auto-generated catch block
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }


    public void play(boolean loop){

        if(clip == null || isRunning())return;
        stop();
        while(!clip.isRunning())
            clip.start();

        if(loop)clip.loop(Clip.LOOP_CONTINUOUSLY);
            
    }
```

and here is an example of what's happening in log form,

```
clip starts running from constructor
same clip starts running from play method
stop method stops the clip from running from the play method
constructor keeps on playing
```

If anyone knows why this is happening it would be nice if you could reply to this. Thanks

edit: I changed clip and fc to not static because I use testing something out with static and then I forgot to change it back to normal

Comment: constructors automatically initialize the variable or in your case the sound....so remove the audio code from the constructor and put it to the play() method

Comment: How do you know it's starting in the constructor?

Comment: unrelated: why does your `play` method use both a `SoundLoader#isRunning()` method and a `clip.isRunning()`method ?

Comment: @jhamon I forgot to change the clip.isRunning() to just isRunning() because clip is private and I didn't know if I was going to use it in other classes so I made isRunning()

Comment: @FedericoklezCulloca I tried to initialize the object in another class where I wanted the sound and when I ran it by accident the sound started to play

Comment: @daksh but in the Clip class, the only method that I'm aware of that can start playing audio is clip.start(). clip.open(...) just passes in input for the clip to play

Comment: the code looks fine ... remove clip.start() from the while loop or maybe try cleaning up your code and rewrite it

Comment: @daksh the reason why I put the while loop there is because sometimes the start method in the Clip class doesn't start straight away and could be missed. meaning that the audio wouldn't actually play.

Answer (score 0):

okay I solved it. It was just a case of me blacking out while I was coding and I was playing the sound in the main method of the project. I'm glad that it wasn't a problem with the Clip class